# AbstractBasicAuthHandler does not support the following scheme: 'Negotiate' [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to open URL in Python which needs username and password.
At the beginning there was this error shown:

```
hereurllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Following tutorials I modded my script to look like this:

```
import urllib.request
url = 'http://example.com'
username = 'user'
password = 'password'
passman = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, username, password)
auth_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(auth_handler)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
```

After that the error disappeared, but another appeared in its place:

```
ValueError: AbstractBasicAuthHandler does not support the following scheme: 'Negotiate'
```

Anybody knows what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to `requests`

> [Basic Authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/)
>
> Many web services that require authentication accept HTTP Basic Auth. This is the simplest kind, and Requests supports it straight out of the box.
>
> Making requests with HTTP Basic Auth is very simple:
>
> ```
> import requests
> from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
> requests.get('http://example.com', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
> <Response [200]>
> ```
>
> In fact, HTTP Basic Auth is so common that Requests provides a handy shorthand for using it:
>
> ```
> requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
> <Response [200]>
> ```
>
> Providing the credentials in a tuple like this is exactly the same as the HTTPBasicAuth example above.

Comment: I did use it. This have shown up:  `TypeError: add_password() missing 1 required positional argument: 'realm'` So I added closing bracket at the end of add_password. Still not working (shows yet another error) but this time it is very likely that something is wrong with my URL.

Comment: `requests` is nice, but a solution with the stdlib would still be appreciated here …